Medieval period movie with life size chess scene played out by village folk, turns into semi-orgy
So around 30? years ago (1984+/-) my parents were watching a movie? on TV (similar theme to today's "Reign" TV show) e.g. set in a medieval time period and I was in the room (likely playing LEGO not watching the TV)
In the only scene I recall, the village folk were standing on a life size chess board and the players on the sidelines barked out the orders... "bishop takes pawn" etc.

Very quickly the game deteriorated as calls were made for "knight 'humps' queen", "{other chess piece} humps the queen too" etc.

Since I was not of the appropriate age to watch such TV programming (and I don't think my parents realized it was going in this direction) I was picked up and taken upstairs before I could even tell what was going on.
(I don't think this was actually an explicit film, more of a raunchy comedy)
However now as an adult, the curiosity is killing me as to what the movie was and (if I can find it) just how bad was it?

This is a Mel Brooks movie called History of the World: Part 1 The chess scene can be found on youtube.
I actually saw this at a drive-in theater.

Wow, that was fast! Awesome! One more item off the bucket list! (and I guess I heard the original wrong... it was "jumps"...)

Classic scene for us "old-timers".

It's good to be the king.

As Yorik answered it is Mel Brooks' History of the World: Part I. There is no Part II. As to "how bad was it?", if you like Mel Brooks movies you should enjoy it as a good laugh. Note: Other Mel Brooks movies you might know better: Space Balls, Blazing Saddles, Young Frankenstein

I love my people. PULL!
